# Calling custom SQL Server stored procedure and URL redirect in VB.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm building an aspx web application. I have a 'Submit' button in my app that calls a custom stored procedure. I'm trying to figure out the code for redirecting users, once the stored procedure is executed.

Here is my VB.NET code for the button + stored procedure:

```
Public Overrides Sub SubmitRequisition1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)
  Try
    Dim CatalogID as Integer
    CatalogID = Ctype(me.CatalogID.text, int32)

    DbUtils.StartTransaction() 
    Dim spName As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedure = Nothing

    Dim firstParameter as BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter = Nothing
    firstParameter = New BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter("@p_CatalogID", CatalogID, System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input)

    Dim parameterList(0) As BaseClasses.Data.StoredProcedureParameter

    parameterList(0) = firstParameter

    spName = New StoredProcedure("DatabaseStoktrak1", "dbo.pHSEProcessWardReqsParams", parameterList) 

    spName.RunNonQuery()

    DbUtils.CommitTransaction() 
Catch ex As Exception
   ' Report the error message to the end user'
    BaseClasses.Utils.MiscUtils.RegisterJScriptAlert(Me, "BUTTON_CLICK_MESSAGE", ex.Message)
    DbUtils.RollBackTransaction()
Finally
    DbUtils.EndTransaction() 
End Try    
End Sub
```

When I insert this line of code

```
Response.Redirect("../LocationCatalog/WARDEditLocationCatalog.aspx")
```

I get a compiler error

> Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'Response' is not declared.

Is this line of code correct, and if so, where does it need to go? Do I need to declare something?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards, Tomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just out of interest does using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../LocationCatalog/WARDEditLocationCatalog.aspx")` instead.

I had this issue with a previous ASP Web Application and this fixed it.

**EDIT**

If not then I believe you may need to declare this to the top of your VB Code Page.

```
Imports System.Web
```

Comment: I can confirm that adding this line of code: HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../LocationCatalog/WARDEditLocationCatalog.aspx") has worked for me. Also at the top of my page I am declaring Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls